# Using Microsoft Vision API throws error "exception of type microsoft.projectoxford.vision.clientexception was thrown"

Tags: vision-api

I am simply using the code sample provided in this link

https://github.com/microsoft/cognitive-vision-windows

and running it provides me this error . did anyone face the same issue ?

[image]

Comment: Please explain what you are trying to do and check if you setup the code to run properly

Comment: please clone this sample and press F5 on your visual studio and let me know if it works or not . 

note : make sure to register for keys and add them in code before running it .